# Why are code blocks separated into different tags?

Tags: tinymce

I am testing this out to see if it will work for my needs. I'm wondering if code is always going to have each line in a separate  tag or if there is a way to combine them? I have tried several methods from typing code directly, to pasting it, to holding shift when hitting the enter key. Every line always ends up inside its own code tag.

Is there a way around that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVCLh.png)

Comment: Perhaps you could create a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows this behavior along with instructions to replicate what you are seeing?  Are you using the Code Sample plugin?  How are you getting `<code>...</code>` into the editor?  What exact steps are you taking to get to the outcome in your image?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.